# Images not Showing in SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui

I am fairly new to SwiftUI and I am attempting to follow a WWDC-2019 app presentation called "Introducing SwiftUI: Building Your First App". so far, everything is working fine except that images are not rendering on the view as expected. My assets xcasettes are properly loaded with nine thumbnails images and each image is affixed with a room name. Below is my the code for the contentView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var rooms: [Room] = []

    var body: some View {
        List(rooms) { room in
            Image(room.thumbnailName)

            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                Text(room.name)
                Text("\(room.capacity) people")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(rooms: testData)
    }
}
```

The code that follows below is an identifiable struct called "Room" and data called "testData"

```
import SwiftUI

struct Room : Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var capacity: Int
    var hasVideo: Bool = false

    var imageName: String { return name}
    var thumbnailName: String { return name + "Thumb"}
}

let testData = [
                Room(name: "Observation Deck", capacity: 6, hasVideo: true),
                Room(name: "Executive Suite", capacity: 8, hasVideo: false),
                Room(name: "Charter Jet", capacity: 16, hasVideo: true),
                Room(name: "Dungeon", capacity: 10, hasVideo: true), 
                Room(name: "Panorama", capacity: 12, hasVideo: false),
                Room(name: "Oceanfront", capacity: 8, hasVideo:false),
                Room(name: "Rainbow Room", capacity: 10, hasVideo: true),
                Room(name: "Pastoral", capacity: 7, hasVideo: false),
                Room(name: "Elephant Room", capacity: 1, hasVideo: false)
]
```

I tried changing the name of the thumbnails to "thumbnailName", "Thumb", "room" but neither worked. I haven't been able to associate the word "Thumb" to anything in the code and I suspect it may be the root of the problem.

As requested, below is a screenshot of the contents of the assets:

[Contents of my assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq6OK.png)

Comment: please show us your assets contents with snapshot

Comment: Here is the screenshot of the content of the assets:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line:

```
var thumbnailName: String { return name + "Thumb"}
```

To this:

```
var thumbnailName: String { return name}
```

The images don‘t change automatically their size just by adding „thumb“ somewhere. Either you add small images with the „thumb“-name in the assets or you just change the size of your images by adding resizable and frame.

Answer (score 0):

The images don‘t change automatically their size just by adding "thumb" in the file ROOM where have your struct code then quit the word "thumb" after go and put the next line of code down of Image (room.thumbnailName)

ROMS file:

```
var thumbnailName: String {return name}
```

contentView:

```
 Image (room.thumbnailName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 32.0, height: 32.0)
```